# My new cipher with numbers

Tags: cipher

I have thought up one simple cipher. Hope it didn't exist before. Try to crack it!

Here is encoded one sentence in English consisting of three words.

$(2_ 2,5_ 2,7_ 5,8_ 5,9_ 4,14_ 4),(6_ 2,7_ 1),(3_ 2,5_ 4,30_ 4,70_ 2)$

- Number with index corresponds to one letter

Hint:

> Numbers are not numbers

Comment: Do each number translate into it's own letter?

Comment: Decoding a cipher like this is very boring unless it has either a very clear direction to start working, or at least a full paragraph of ciphertext, preferably more. I do not want to spend an hour throwing random crap at your puzzle and checking whether the result is English. (Credit to @Lopsy for the copy-paste text.)

Comment: @xnor I actually tried to disprove you for a while, but after that last edit, I do believe you are right.

Comment: I vote for re-opening, but I would like to ask Somnium to edit it with more information (not hints) to make it a better/solvable puzzle. I also think the additional encryption of the solution is not a good idea.

Comment: Nice! A very clever puzzle.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The answer is:

> winter is here

Method:

> - spell each integer (excluding index numbers) - two five seven eight  etc.
>  - select letters from each word using index numbers - w i n t  etc.

Comment: Nice one! This must be it.

Comment: D@rn! I thought of part 1 right away, but part two never crossed my mind, so it didn't go anywhere!

Comment: Nice one! That was *really* good.