# Can you decipher the hidden message in this Christmas card image?

Tags: cipher, visual, seasonal

Sent by a friend in Germany. I have no idea what it says yet!...

[image: Xmas puzzle image]

Comment: It's interesting that there are 7 sharp corners in each "bundle", including the wrapped present.

Comment: Yes this is all I have noticed too! My friend said it was to celebrate the arbitrary "endpoint" of the year. So maybe "Endpoint" is a clue but it might not be!........

Comment: Could the bundles represent letters? The far left one looks a bit like a C, the rightmost one could be an M, and the top left one could be an A.

Comment: Well done Julian Rosen !!

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The message reads:

> HaPpY 2015

How to decode:

> As noted in the comments, each figure has seven sharp corners. Treating a sharp left turn as $1$ and a sharp right turn as $0$, each figure encodes a 7-digit binary number. These numbers are $$1001000,\, 1100001,\, 1010000,\, 1110000,\, 1011001,\, 0110010,\, 0110000,\, 0110001,\, 0110101.$$ If we interpret these numbers as [ASCII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII#ASCII_printable_code_chart), we get a sequence of characters:
>   **H**,  **a**,  **P**,  **p**,  **Y**,  **2**,  **0**,  **1**,  **5**.