# The Hunting of the Snark: Given ciphertext and plaintext, what cipher is used?

Tags: cipher

This is a [cryptogram](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptogram) puzzle.

Below is some text; each section of the original text ('plaintext') is followed by an encoded version of that text (the 'ciphertext').

Your challenge is to explain the encoding for each section.

Most of the ciphers are 'pen-and-paper', meaning that you don't need a computer to decode them; but for at least one of them you *will* probably need help from your computer (unless you have a lot of patience to go with your pen and paper). Some of them are easier than others. :)

You may find the [Rumkin.com cipher tools](http://rumkin.com/tools/cipher/) useful, also [cryptii.com](http://cryptii.com/). Also you might find this post here on Puzzling.SE useful: [What characteristics of a ciphertext can be indicators of a particular cipher?](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/5905/what-characteristics-of-a-ciphertext-can-be-indicators-of-a-particular-cipher)

Plaintext - "The Hunting of the Snark" by Lewis Carroll, fit 8:

0: Title

> Fit the Eighth 
>   The Vanishing
>
> hthgiE eht tiF
>   Gur Inavfuvat

1.

> They sought it with thimbles, they sought it with care; 
>     They
>   pursued it with forks and hope; 
>  They threatened its life with a
>   railway-share; 
>     They charmed it with smiles and soap.
>
> Moif mbnouz wy ppxz ghzwusiz, nuxg fuilaa ml jikr vhvl;
>   Nuxg cafxnlh ag wzda msyef tvq ncux;
>   Alwl tybxhxlhrw qgy znyl aagh r btppdul-lpnxs;
>   Yalc uuaiwxk ma qvmp fswqxz efq sfki.

2.

> They shuddered to think that the chase might fail, 
>     And the
>   Beaver, excited at last, 
>  Went bounding along on the tip of its
>   tail, 
>     For the daylight was nearly past.
>
> Tdam eto f ilste txtnh twse s,edtop,aeet gn,lnnioh
>   uicaeiW  aes.eh  vabgo lr  ht esit 
>   s  adkalBenlildnh tiAr uo Fgyhh fhc,gethatr 
>   te a  n  yayothd ad trtpdnhi teati

3.

> "There is Thingumbob shouting!" the Bellman said, 
>     "He is
>   shouting like mad, only hark! 
>  He is waving his hands, he is
>   wagging his head, 
>     He has certainly found a Snark!"
>
> BAABAAABBBAABAABAAAAAABAA ABAAABAAAB BAABAAABBBABAAAABBAAAABBABAABBABABBAAAABABBABAAAAB BAAABAABBBABBABBAABBBAABAABAAAABBAAAABBA BAABAAABBBAABAA AAAABAABAAABABAABABAABABBAAAAAABBAA BAAABAAAAAABAAAAAABB AABBBAABAA ABAAABAAAB BAAABAABBBABBABBAABBBAABAABAAAABBAAAABBA ABABAABAAAABAABAABAA ABABBAAAAAAAABB ABBABABBAAABABABABBA AABBBAAAAABAAAAABAAB AABBBAABAA ABAAABAAAB BABAAAAAAABAABBABAAAABBAAAABBA AABBBABAAABAAAB AABBBAAAAAABBAAAAABBBAAAB AABBBAABAA ABAAABAAAB BABAAAAAAAAABBAAABBAABAAAABBAAAABBA AABBBABAAABAAAB AABBBAABAAAAAAAAAABB AABBBAABAA AABBBAAAAABAAAB AAABAAABAABAAAABAABAAAAAAABAAAABBAAABABABABBA AABABABBABBAABBABBAAAAABB AAAAA BAAABABBAAAAAAABAAAAABAAB

4.

> They
>   gazed in delight, while the Butcher exclaimed 
>     "He was always a
>   desperate wag!" 
>  They beheld him—their Baker—their hero unnamed—
>   
>     On the top of a neighbouring crag,
>
> Lwpf ktstw wp pjztubz, lyczp alx Tnfpiqi sazugmqjr 
>   "Ss ztk quccdk p noevbazap dez!" 
>   Lxxe oqaswb bqw—dastu Utdtd—miqcu sodc vjfpisg— 
>   Pf cbr vgg iq y mkmxahflvofw vjcs,

5.

> Erect and sublime, for one moment of time, 
>     In the next, that
>   wild figure they saw 
>  (As if stung by a spasm) plunge into a
>   chasm, 
>     While they waited and listened in awe.
>
> . .-. . -.-. - / .- -. -.. / ... ..- -... .-.. .. -- . --..-- / ..-. --- .-. / --- -. . / -- --- -- . -. - / --- ..-. / - .. -- . --..-- .-.-.. / .. -. / - .... . / -. . -..- - --..-- / - .... .- - / .-- .. .-.. -.. / ..-. .. --. ..- .-. . / - .... . -.-- / ... .- .-- .-.-.. -.--. .- ... / .. ..-. / ... - ..- -. --. / -... -.-- / .- / ... .--. .- ... -- -.--.- / .--. .-.. ..- -. --. . / .. -. - --- / .- / -.-. .... .- ... -- --..-- .-.-.. / .-- .... .. .-.. . / - .... . -.-- / .-- .- .. - . -.. / .- -. -.. / .-.. .. ... - . -. . -.. / .. -. / .- .-- . .-.-.-

6.

> "It's a Snark!" was the sound that first came to their ears,
>   And seemed almost too good to be true. 
>  Then followed a torrent of
>   laughter and cheers: 
>     Then the ominous words "It's a Boo—"
>
> "KV'V V RGWZX!" GXI SPN UQCOA UKJY NDZBB RWDJ CW FNKBT ARXR, 
>   ELN AJKPDV HHDSNJ FLZ WKQY AP QO IXBK. 
>   GZLG XSZJWKKY Y RQAXHSD SU MMKQJZNZ GSF HNKNTG: 
>   BVHS DCQ TAARIJT XSEFI "VI'V D VJN—"

7.

> Then, silence. Some fancied they heard in the air 
>     A weary and
>   wandering sigh 
>  That sounded like "-jum!" but the others declare
>   
>     It was only a breeze that went by.
>
> ```
> 101+105+103+104+116+121+45+102+111+117+114+35+111+110+101+32+104+117+110+100+114+101+100+32+97+110+100+32+102+111+117+114+35+111+110+101+32+104+117+110+100+114+101+100+32+97+110+100+32+111+110+101+35+111+110+101+32+104+117+110+100+114+101+100+32+97+110+100+32+116+101+110+35+102+111+114+116+121+45+102+111+117+114+35+116+104+105+114+116+121+45+116+119+111+35+111+110+101+32+104+117+110+100+114+101+100+32+97+110+100+32+102+105+102+116+101+101+110+35+111+110+101+32+104+117+110+100+114+101+100+32+97+110+100+32+102+105+118+101+35+111+110+101+32+104+117+110+100+114+101+100+32+97+110+100+32+101+105+103+104+116+35+111+110+101+32+104+117+110+100+114+101+100+32+97+110+100+32+111+110+101+35+111+110+101+32+104+117+110+100+114+101+100+32+97+110+100+32+116+101+110+35+110+105+110+101+116+121+45+110+105+110+101+35+111+110+101+32+104+117+110+100+114+101+100+32+97+110+100+32+111+110+101+35+102+111+114+116+121+45+115+105+120+35+116+104+105+114+116+121+45+116+119+111+35+101+105+103+104+116+121+45+116+104+114+101+101+35+111+110+101+32+104+117+110+100+114+101+100+32+97+110+100+32+101+108+101+118+101+110+35+111+110+101+32+104+117+110+100+114+101+100+32+97+110+100+32+110+105+110+101+35+111+110+101+32+104+117+110+100+114+101+100+32+97+110+100+32+111+110+101+35+116+104+105+114+116+121+45+116+119+111+35+111+110+101+32+104+117+110+100+114+101+100+32+97+110+100+32+116+119+111+35+110+105+110+101+116+121+45+115+101+118+101+110+35+111+110+101+32+104+117+110+100+114+101+100+32+97+110+100+32+116+101+110+35+110+105+110+101+116+121+45+110+105+110+101+35+111+110+101+32+104+117+110+100+114+101+100+32+97+110+100+32+102+105+118+101+35+111+110+101+32+104+117+110+100+114+101+100+32+97+110+100+32+111+110+101+35+111+110+101+32+104+117+110+100+114+101+100+35+116+104+105+114+116+121+45+116+119+111+35+111+110+101+32+104+117+110+100+114+101+100+32+97+110+100+32+115+105+120+116+101+101+110+35+111+110+101+32+104+117+110+100+114+101+100+32+97+110+100+32+102+111+117+114+35+111+110+101+32+104+117+110+100+114+101+100+32+97+110+100+32+111+110+101+35+111+110+101+32+104+117+110+100+114+101+100+32+97+110+100+32+116+119+101+110+116+121+45+111+110+101+35+116+104+105+114+116+121+45+116+119+111+35+111+110+101+32+104+117+110+100+114+101+100+32+97+110+100+32+102+111+117+114+35+111+110+101+32+104+117+110+100+114+101+100+32+97+110+100+32+111+110+101+35+110+105+110+101+116+121+45+115+101+118+101+110+35+111+110+101+32+104+117+110+100+114+101+100+32+97+110+100+32+102+111+117+114+116+101+101+110+35+111+110+101+32+104+117+110+100+114+101+100+35+116+104+105+114+116+121+45+116+119+111+35+111+110+101+32+104+117+110+100+114+101+100+32+97+110+100+32+102+105+118+101+35+111+110+101+32+104+117+110+100+114+101+100+32+97+110+100+32+116+101+110+35+116+104+105+114+116+121+45+116+119+111+35+111+110+101+32+104+117+110+100+114+101+100+32+97+110+100+32+115+105+120+116+101+101+110+35+111+110+101+32+104+117+110+100+114+101+100+32+97+110+100+32+102+111+117+114+35+111+110+101+32+104+117+110+100+114+101+100+32+97+110+100+32+111+110+101+35+116+104+105+114+116+121+45+116+119+111+35+110+105+110+101+116+121+45+115+101+118+101+110+35+111+110+101+32+104+117+110+100+114+101+100+32+97+110+100+32+102+105+118+101+35+111+110+101+32+104+117+110+100+114+101+100+32+97+110+100+32+102+111+117+114+116+101+101+110+35+116+101+110+35+116+104+105+114+116+121+45+116+119+111+35+116+104+105+114+116+121+45+116+119+111+35+116+104+105+114+116+121+45+116+119+111+35+115+105+120+116+121+45+102+105+118+101+35+116+104+105+114+116+121+45+116+119+111+35+111+110+101+32+104+117+110+100+114+101+100+32+97+110+100+32+110+105+110+101+116+101+101+110+35+111+110+101+32+104+117+110+100+114+101+100+32+97+110+100+32+111+110+101+35+110+105+110+101+116+121+45+115+101+118+101+110+35+111+110+101+32+104+117+110+100+114+101+100+32+97+110+100+32+102+111+117+114+116+101+101+110+35+111+110+101+32+104+117+110+100+114+101+100+32+97+110+100+32+116+119+101+110+116+121+45+111+110+101+35+116+104+105+114+116+121+45+116+119+111+35+110+105+110+101+116+121+45+115+101+118+101+110+35+111+110+101+32+104+117+110+100+114+101+100+32+97+110+100+32+116+101+110+35+111+110+101+32+104+117+110+100+114+101+100+35+116+104+105+114+116+121+45+116+119+111+35+111+110+101+32+104+117+110+100+114+101+100+32+97+110+100+32+110+105+110+101+116+101+101+110+35+110+105+110+101+116+121+45+115+101+118+101+110+35+111+110+101+32+104+117+110+100+114+101+100+32+97+110+100+32+116+101+110+35+111+110+101+32+104+117+110+100+114+101+100+35+111+110+101+32+104+117+110+100+114+101+100+32+97+110+100+32+111+110+101+35+111+110+101+32+104+117+110+100+114+101+100+32+97+110+100+32+102+111+117+114+116+101+101+110+35+111+110+101+32+104+117+110+100+114+101+100+32+97+110+100+32+102+105+118+101+35+111+110+101+32+104+117+110+100+114+101+100+32+97+110+100+32+116+101+110+35+111+110+101+32+104+117+110+100+114+101+100+32+97+110+100+32+116+104+114+101+101+35+116+104+105+114+116+121+45+116+119+111+35+111+110+101+32+104+117+110+100+114+101+100+32+97+110+100+32+102+105+102+116+101+101+110+35+111+110+101+32+104+117+110+100+114+101+100+32+97+110+100+32+102+105+118+101+35+111+110+101+32+104+117+110+100+114+101+100+32+97+110+100+32+116+104+114+101+101+35+111+110+101+32+104+117+110+100+114+101+100+32+97+110+100+32+102+111+117+114+35+116+101+110+35+101+105+103+104+116+121+45+102+111+117+114+35+111+110+101+32+104+117+110+100+114+101+100+32+97+110+100+32+102+111+117+114+35+110+105+110+101+116+121+45+115+101+118+101+110+35+111+110+101+32+104+117+110+100+114+101+100+32+97+110+100+32+115+105+120+116+101+101+110+35+116+104+105+114+116+121+45+116+119+111+35+111+110+101+32+104+117+110+100+114+101+100+32+97+110+100+32+102+105+102+116+101+101+110+35+111+110+101+32+104+117+110+100+114+101+100+32+97+110+100+32+101+108+101+118+101+110+35+111+110+101+32+104+117+110+100+114+101+100+32+97+110+100+32+115+101+118+101+110+116+101+101+110+35+111+110+101+32+104+117+110+100+114+101+100+32+97+110+100+32+116+101+110+35+111+110+101+32+104+117+110+100+114+101+100+35+111+110+101+32+104+117+110+100+114+101+100+32+97+110+100+32+111+110+101+35+111+110+101+32+104+117+110+100+114+101+100+35+116+104+105+114+116+121+45+116+119+111+35+111+110+101+32+104+117+110+100+114+101+100+32+97+110+100+32+101+105+103+104+116+35+111+110+101+32+104+117+110+100+114+101+100+32+97+110+100+32+102+105+118+101+35+111+110+101+32+104+117+110+100+114+101+100+32+97+110+100+32+115+101+118+101+110+35+111+110+101+32+104+117+110+100+114+101+100+32+97+110+100+32+111+110+101+35+116+104+105+114+116+121+45+116+119+111+35+116+104+105+114+116+121+45+102+111+117+114+35+102+111+114+116+121+45+102+105+118+101+35+111+110+101+32+104+117+110+100+114+101+100+32+97+110+100+32+115+105+120+35+111+110+101+32+104+117+110+100+114+101+100+32+97+110+100+32+115+101+118+101+110+116+101+101+110+35+111+110+101+32+104+117+110+100+114+101+100+32+97+110+100+32+110+105+110+101+35+116+104+105+114+116+121+45+116+104+114+101+101+35+116+104+105+114+116+121+45+102+111+117+114+35+116+104+105+114+116+121+45+116+119+111+35+110+105+110+101+116+121+45+101+105+103+104+116+35+111+110+101+32+104+117+110+100+114+101+100+32+97+110+100+32+115+101+118+101+110+116+101+101+110+35+111+110+101+32+104+117+110+100+114+101+100+32+97+110+100+32+115+105+120+116+101+101+110+35+116+104+105+114+116+121+45+116+119+111+35+111+110+101+32+104+117+110+100+114+101+100+32+97+110+100+32+115+105+120+116+101+101+110+35+111+110+101+32+104+117+110+100+114+101+100+32+97+110+100+32+102+111+117+114+35+111+110+101+32+104+117+110+100+114+101+100+32+97+110+100+32+111+110+101+35+116+104+105+114+116+121+45+116+119+111+35+111+110+101+32+104+117+110+100+114+101+100+32+97+110+100+32+101+108+101+118+101+110+35+111+110+101+32+104+117+110+100+114+101+100+32+97+110+100+32+115+105+120+116+101+101+110+35+111+110+101+32+104+117+110+100+114+101+100+32+97+110+100+32+102+111+117+114+35+111+110+101+32+104+117+110+100+114+101+100+32+97+110+100+32+111+110+101+35+111+110+101+32+104+117+110+100+114+101+100+32+97+110+100+32+102+111+117+114+116+101+101+110+35+111+110+101+32+104+117+110+100+114+101+100+32+97+110+100+32+102+105+102+116+101+101+110+35+116+104+105+114+116+121+45+116+119+111+35+111+110+101+32+104+117+110+100+114+101+100+35+111+110+101+32+104+117+110+100+114+101+100+32+97+110+100+32+111+110+101+35+110+105+110+101+116+121+45+110+105+110+101+35+111+110+101+32+104+117+110+100+114+101+100+32+97+110+100+32+101+105+103+104+116+35+110+105+110+101+116+121+45+115+101+118+101+110+35+111+110+101+32+104+117+110+100+114+101+100+32+97+110+100+32+102+111+117+114+116+101+101+110+35+111+110+101+32+104+117+110+100+114+101+100+32+97+110+100+32+111+110+101+35+116+101+110+35+116+104+105+114+116+121+45+116+119+111+35+116+104+105+114+116+121+45+116+119+111+35+116+104+105+114+116+121+45+116+119+111+35+115+101+118+101+110+116+121+45+116+104+114+101+101+35+111+110+101+32+104+117+110+100+114+101+100+32+97+110+100+32+115+105+120+116+101+101+110+35+116+104+105+114+116+121+45+116+119+111+35+111+110+101+32+104+117+110+100+114+101+100+32+97+110+100+32+110+105+110+101+116+101+101+110+35+110+105+110+101+116+121+45+115+101+118+101+110+35+111+110+101+32+104+117+110+100+114+101+100+32+97+110+100+32+102+105+102+116+101+101+110+35+116+104+105+114+116+121+45+116+119+111+35+111+110+101+32+104+117+110+100+114+101+100+32+97+110+100+32+101+108+101+118+101+110+35+111+110+101+32+104+117+110+100+114+101+100+32+97+110+100+32+116+101+110+35+111+110+101+32+104+117+110+100+114+101+100+32+97+110+100+32+101+105+103+104+116+35+111+110+101+32+104+117+110+100+114+101+100+32+97+110+100+32+116+119+101+110+116+121+45+111+110+101+35+116+104+105+114+116+121+45+116+119+111+35+110+105+110+101+116+121+45+115+101+118+101+110+35+116+104+105+114+116+121+45+116+119+111+35+110+105+110+101+116+121+45+101+105+103+104+116+35+111+110+101+32+104+117+110+100+114+101+100+32+97+110+100+32+102+111+117+114+116+101+101+110+35+111+110+101+32+104+117+110+100+114+101+100+32+97+110+100+32+111+110+101+35+111+110+101+32+104+117+110+100+114+101+100+32+97+110+100+32+111+110+101+35+111+110+101+32+104+117+110+100+114+101+100+32+97+110+100+32+116+119+101+110+116+121+45+116+119+111+35+111+110+101+32+104+117+110+100+114+101+100+32+97+110+100+32+111+110+101+35+116+104+105+114+116+121+45+116+119+111+35+111+110+101+32+104+117+110+100+114+101+100+32+97+110+100+32+115+105+120+116+101+101+110+35+111+110+101+32+104+117+110+100+114+101+100+32+97+110+100+32+102+111+117+114+35+110+105+110+101+116+121+45+115+101+118+101+110+35+111+110+101+32+104+117+110+100+114+101+100+32+97+110+100+32+115+105+120+116+101+101+110+35+116+104+105+114+116+121+45+116+119+111+35+111+110+101+32+104+117+110+100+114+101+100+32+97+110+100+32+110+105+110+101+116+101+101+110+35+111+110+101+32+104+117+110+100+114+101+100+32+97+110+100+32+111+110+101+35+111+110+101+32+104+117+110+100+114+101+100+32+97+110+100+32+116+101+110+35+111+110+101+32+104+117+110+100+114+101+100+32+97+110+100+32+115+105+120+116+101+101+110+35+116+104+105+114+116+121+45+116+119+111+35+110+105+110+101+116+121+45+101+105+103+104+116+35+111+110+101+32+104+117+110+100+114+101+100+32+97+110+100+32+116+119+101+110+116+121+45+111+110+101+35+102+111+114+116+121+45+115+105+120
> ```

8.

> They hunted till darkness came on, but they found 
>     Not a
>   button, or feather, or mark, 
>  By which they could tell that they
>   stood on the ground 
>     Where the Baker had met with the Snark.
>
> Moif bhgbrj hnes hsekeolz gyty bg, fxm bspb ffeah 
>   Fgv a nyhgph, hk miyyvye, re atrl, 
>   Vr pvvqy yler jslzu fecv ufwa bjlr zxmqr iy wai rchbnw 
>   Poipw mvs Eoxxy lgu ayg zeal klx Zrbru.

9.

> In the midst of the word he was trying to say, 
>     In the midst of
>   his laughter and glee, 
>  He had softly and suddenly vanished away—
>   
>     For the Snark was a Boojum, you see.
>
> In the midst of the word he was trying to say, 
>   In the midst of his laughter and glee, 
>   He had softly and suddenly vanished away— 
>   For the Snark was a Boojum, you see.

Feedback / constructive comments / suggestions on the puzzle and the ciphers themselves are welcome, as well as actual answers. Partial answers are welcome, in the spirit of teamwork.

Comment: To be clear: The clear-text does *not* contain a hint why a particular cipher was used, does it?

Comment: @BmyGuest, no, it doesn't.

Comment: Although that's a good idea for next time!

Comment: +1 for this question. Not because it would be extremely creative or complex, but because it is very nice resource to cite when demonstrating the most common ciphers. And the tool link of course.

Comment: Thanks @BmyGuest! A demo of some of the most common ciphers, inviting answers which explain how they're spotted and solved, is pretty much what I was going for. With a few more difficult ones thrown in for fun! :)

Comment: Are you sure that #9 is correct?

Comment: @WChargin, yeah, I'm just making a joke. That's a "Caesar 26" substitution cipher.

Comment: I've just amended part 7 to make it more fun. It's solvable with either version.

Comment: Technically, of course, they *could* all be [codes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_%28cryptography%29) or [one-time pads](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-time_pad).

Comment: @IlmariKaronen ... technically they *could*, but I promise that none of them *are*. I wouldn't consider that fair. ;)

Comment: Since this is a community based solve, with different parts being solved by different people, perhaps there should be a single answer by Community Wiki with all the answers in?

Comment: @ForIInRange, that sounds like a good plan to me! It would solve my "who do I award the green tick to?" problem. :) Although 6 is as yet not-totally-solved.

Comment: I'm pretty sure #6 is from an Enigma machine (as seen on Cryptii) due to the lack of repetitions, the lack of periodic phenomena, and the uniform letter and bigram frequencies. I'm not aware of any ready-made tools for a known-plaintext attack on Enigma. I found an Enigma solver that implements Gillogly's attack and replaced the N-gram scoring functions with a simple count of correct plaintext letters, but had no success finding the key settings. I wonder if this is because the text is so short?

Comment: Though, the solver I used only implements the model M3 rotors, and wouldn't find the key settings if you had set Cryptii's Enigma to any of the other models. What program or method would you recommend we use to recover the key settings, given the plain and ciphertext?

Answer (score 6):

I guess I'll start with the elephants in the room:

The **First Line** of the **Title**:

> The text is simply reversed. "Fit the Eighth" becomes "hthgiE eht tiF"

The **Second Line** of the **Title**:

> A Caesarian Shift Cipher is used. This involves shifting each letter a fixed number of places in the alphabet, in this case 13 places.

For **Paragraph 3**:

> Bacon's Cipher. Each letter has a 5-bit representation, in As and Bs.

For **Paragraph 5**:

> Morse Code. Each letter has a dot-and-dash representation.

For **Paragraph 9**:

> Caesar Shift of 0?

Comment: Correction: #9 uses the encryption algorithm from the research paper http://www.pruefziffernberechnung.de/Originaldokumente/2rot13.pdf

Comment: @Lopsy Ah, how could I have missed it? I knew it looked familiar but I just couldn't put my finger on what it was.

Answer (score 6):

**Cipher 1** is

> Vigenère with the key "thehuntingofthesnark".  The different encodings of "They" tipped me off to look at a polyalphabetic cipher.  After getting the first 4-5 letters of the key by trial and error, the rest of the key was easy to guess.

**Cipher 2** is

> Decoding the plaintext with [Skip 13](http://rumkin.com/tools/cipher/skip.php).  That is, take every 13th character.  The tool does this in "Decode" mode.  The fact that the ciphertext consisted of exactly the characters of the plaintext made it clear it was some kind of transposition cipher.

When this is used as the plaintext:

```
They shuddered to think that the chase might fail,
   And the Beaver, excited at last,
Went bounding along on the tip of its tail,
   For the daylight was nearly past.
```

I get this ciphertext:

```
Tdam eto f ilste txtnh twse s,edtop,aeet gn,lnnioh
 uicaeiW  aes.eh  vabgo lr  ht esit
s  adkalBenlildnh tiAr uo Fgyhh fhc,gethatr
te a  n  yayothd ad trtpdnhi teati
```

The whitespace in neither matches your example, but I suspect browser/Stack Exchange formatting is to blame for that.

**Cipher 7** is

> Converted to decimal ASCII codes (84 104 101 110...),
>  then spelled out and separated with # (eighty-four#one hundred and four#one hundred and one#one hundred and ten...),
>  then converted to decimal ASCII codes again. (101+105+103+104+116+121+45+102+111+117+114+35+111+110+101+32+104+117+110+100+114+101+100+32+97+110+100+32+102+111+117+114+35+111+110+101+32+104+117+110+100+114+101+100+32+97+110+100+32+111+110+101+35+111+110+101+32+104+117+110+100+114+101+100+32+97+110+100+32+116+101+110...)
>
> Boy, am I glad I didn't do that by hand.

**Cipher 8** is

> [Vigenère Autokey](http://rumkin.com/tools/cipher/vigenere-autokey.php) with a null Alphabet Key (ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ) and passphrase "thehuntingofthesnark".  Since this started with the same "Moif" for "They" as #2, I figured it must be related.

Comment: Good work, @Simon. ;) Ok to ignore white space differences, for exactly the reasons you say.

Comment: Making progress! :)

Answer (score 4):

**Section 4** is a:

> **[keyed Vigenère cipher](http://rumkin.com/tools/cipher/vigenere-keyed.php)** with a passphrase and an alphabet key.
>  The passphrase is **thehuntingofthesnark**
>  The alphabet key is **Boojum** (or bojum to avoid duplicate letters)
>
>  Here are the steps that I used:
>
>  - subtract the plaintext from the ciphertext (mod-26) to try to identify the type of cipher.  A majority of the characters are repeating at intervals of 20 or multiples of 20.  It looks like a messed-up Vigenère cipher with a likely passphrase length of 20 characters. Therefore, assume that the same 20 character passphrase is being used (thehuntingofthesnark).
>
>  - split the plaintext and the ciphertext into 20 character segments and map the ciphertext to 20 rows of alphabets as shown in [this example](http://cryptogram.org/cdb/aca.info/aca.and.you/chapter_09.pdf#QUAGM3) (this specific cipher is also called Quagmire III.)
>
>  - and **yes**, fragments of the passphrase now show up under the plaintext letter **B**.  But, because the passphrase is long, only 25% of the map is populated (130 characters in a 20x26 grid) and the alphabet key is not obvious.
>
>  - so back to the puzzle to find words that start with B which are Beaver, Bellman, Baker, Butcher, and Boojum. Boojum gives a match for the ciphertext so the analysis is **complete**.

**Section 6** could be a:

> **Vigenère cipher** with a null alphabet or a mixed alphabet.
>
>  With an alphabet key of BOJUM, the passphrase would be:
>
> ```
> oojpzvqdglrszadgpuiyfjxmcvddciqutivnmaljxkazuzeitaizlcxurwenkyiipqhnqsraxaplcvlrhlvqaqsypkaumkrtpzgdqaddamjamadjqcgumkvfsosuhzoorpjsfrjjvol
> ```
>
> With a null alphabet, the passphrase would be:
>
> ```
> ccdvztwinkxqzijccibxbdjfivijipwrfjimggtcwrgzeykifgdzshwrevqmxlqwcvhbpkpghgnshtseoyiogvyycjgdfkepbmqkcgjigfcfggjcoiodfkvmfoseupbbencqnpdduvz
> ```
>
> However, these passphrases are the full length of the ciphertext which is no different than enciphering with a one-time pad.  So unless, there is some meaning to these passphrases, this solution for Section 6 is likely incorrect.

Comment: Nice work! I'd forgotten about this one. ;)

Comment: 6 is really pretty hard. It's not double encryption though.

Comment: @AE - I have run out of ideas to try for Section 6.

Answer (score 1):

This is *work in progress*:

Title

> Simply revers. (solved with this [tool](http://www.wired.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/brain1.jpg) as a helper)

Section #3

> **Baconian Cipher** (solved with this [tool](http://rumkin.com/tools/cipher/baconian.php) as a helper)

Section #5

> Rather obvious Morse code (solved with this [tool](http://gc.de/gc/morse/)as a helper)

Section #9

> Is *funny*! :c)  ( Replacement cipher with a->a b->b c->c etc.)

Comment: I'm glad you like the joke in section 9. :) I call it a "Caesar shift 26".

Answer (score 1):

Title

> First line is reversed.
>  The second line is simple substitution cipher, shifted by 13.

3.

> Bacon Cipher

5.

> Morse code

9.

> Is the same thing?

Answer (score 1):

Taking a wild punt on #6. Is it an Enigma machine encryption? I say this because it has the unusual property that no letter ever gets encoded to itself.

Edit: then again, this also applies to #4, the other uncracked message. Gah.

Comment: Oooooo, you might be onto something there! ;)