# Do you know who I am?

Tags: riddle

I am an instrument of fear and propaganda,

I am bringer of ill news.

But if you see me, you may laugh,

I can distract you on a bad day.

The world is glued to me,

Loving but one part of me.

You complain of the cost of me,

And can't use me unless you have, well,

I would love to tell you, but then, of course, I'd have to kill you.

Comment: The 1st five lines perfectly describe the nightly news. :)

Comment: Hahaha... Very funny

Comment: Great to see the [unofficial slogan of Puzzling SE](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/6401/christmas-day-cryptogram-riddle#comment21162_6401) incorporated in a riddle! ;-)

Comment: This feels like it could have multiple answers.

Comment: I think it may be ambiguous too.... Sorry, my um.. second riddle or so

Comment: It seems like the last line have multiple references (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/I%27d_Tell_You_I_Love_You,_But_Then_I%27d_Have_to_Kill_You) as well!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you

> Television

I am an instrument of fear and propaganda,

I am bringer of ill news.

> These two are relatively obvious, as network news stations love to fearmonger for ratings

But if you see me, you may laugh,

> Not all shows on TV are bad.

I can distract you on a bad day.

> TV could arguably be based on the same concepts as musical theatre, which was designed to act as a distraction during bad times

The world is glued to me,

> The basic idiom "glued to the television set" comes to mind

Loving but one part of me.

> People love TV, but they hate cable companies

You complain of the cost of me,

> Because they are exorbitantly expensive

And can't use me unless you have, well,

> Nowadays, however, television sets require either a good internet connection or a cable subscription in order to get anything outside the basic OTA channels

I would love to tell you, but then, of course, I'd have to kill you.

> Who doesn't love to quote their favorite tv shows and movies? Also, if this line were actually finished, it would be a large give away to the answer of the riddle.

Comment: Your train of thought was almost exactly the same as mine, good job.  The last line was in reference to the line from Sherlock(if I'm not mistaken), which is a TV show.  Just wanted to slip it in somehow :-)

Answer (score 2):

Are you

> a smartphone?

I am an instrument of fear,

> lots of people fears to forget or lose theirs

I am bringer of ill news.

> when the phone ring, you might have some bad news

But if you see me, you may laugh,

> depending on what's playing on it, you might laugh

I can distract you on a bad day.

> if you read funny stuff on it, it might cheer you up

The world is glued to me,

> everybody is looking at their, in the metro, in the bus even in their car

Loving but one part of me.
You complain of the cost of me,

> smart phone can be expensive as data plans

And can't use me unless you have, well,

> you can't use it if you don't have one.

I would love to tell you, but then, of course, I'd have to kill you.

> I think this one is not related to the smartphone but as a joke from OP saying we need to find it because he wont tell us :)

Comment: The item you named works, but I was thinking of something else.  The last line does have meaning.

Answer (score 1):

Are you

> heroin (or similar narcotics)?

I am an instrument of fear and propaganda,

> Anti-drug campaigns often emphasize the adverse effects of drugs to scare teenagers away from them

I am bringer of ill news.

> If you die of overdose, your family will have bad news

But if you see me, you may laugh,

> You may be very happy when you are high and you see more drugs

I can distract you on a bad day.

> You can be distracted by getting high

The world is glued to me,

> Addicts are glued to drugs. Dealers may also be dependent on them (financially)

Loving but one part of me.

> Love the high, but not the adverse effects

You complain of the cost of me,

> Last time I checked, heroin is quite expensive

And can't use me unless you have, well,

> Can't use drugs if you don't have drugs. Or if this is a continuation of the previous sentence, then can't use drugs if you don't have money

I would love to tell you, but then, of course, I'd have to kill you.

> To understand the high you will have to try it, but each time you take it you decrease your life expectancy

Comment: Interesting idea, but no.