# Mousehunt cryptogram

Tags: cipher, symbols

I found this puzzle within the game [Mousehunt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MouseHunt_%28game%29)

[image]

It didn't seem to match any rune system that I know of. Rotating the image also didn't seem to show any useful information, although the first word when the image is rotated 180 degrees looked suspiciously like "First".

For context, a list of other images are also visible [here on the official wiki.](http://mhwiki.hitgrab.com/wiki/index.php/Torn_Pages_of_Plankrun%27s_Journal)

Comment: Some general tips: http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/5905/

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[image: solution]

If you swap the upper part of each line with the lower part, then flip the image horizontally, you get the message "WELCOME TO YOUR PRISON.  FIRST HUNTER."