# What is encrypted in this image?

Tags: steganography

[image: http://imgur.com/r6n5cBe]

In the [image above](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dAcfN.jpg)  apparently has a hidden link?? I don't know how to do this (even if it may seem simple for some) however I don't believe it's anything malicious. It's a part of a puzzle, but even I don't get where it will ultimately lead.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/szEs3Hhq

Comment: Check out this page on wikipedia to learn about steganography: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steganography

Comment: Some sites on SE have the ability to post an answer, but is hidden until clicked.  Does that feature exist on Sec.SE? May be good for Red/Blue teams scenarios / documentation

Comment: I've managed to follow the puzzle up until the clue is `TITLEOFJPG`. Can you direct us to where you found the image? A reverse Google Image search turns up nothing.

Comment: @GabrielSantos How did you find that URL?

Comment: @ColeJohnson It's encoded into the image using `steghide`, without a passphrase.

Comment: @ColeJohnson See this: https://futureboy.us/stegano/decinput.html

Answer (score 47):

We begin by using [steghide](https://futureboy.us/stegano/decinput.html) to reveal the payload:

```
http://pastebin.com/szEs3Hhq
```

[The link](http://pastebin.com/szEs3Hhq) brings us to a paste where we get

```
you've done well. Go deeper, and the rewards can be found. Difficulty will increase as you solve each test.
May you find your meaning.

486578206973206561737920656e6f7567682e204e65656420746f20676f206465657065723f0d0a0d0a4441426d696e46236d696e47444741

Let the hunt begin.
```

The `0d0a` in there looks very suspicious (`\r\n` in C-like languages). Could it be a hex encoded ASCII string? Decoding gets us:

```
Hex is easy enough. Need to go deeper?

DABminF#minGDGA
```

A chord progression? For D Major, that is `I V vi iii IV I IV V`. A Google search doesn't turn up anything. Maybe just search the chord names? (EDIT: It's Pachelbel's "Canon in D")

That turns up a Reddit [/r/N001109](https://www.reddit.com/r/N001109/comments/2wjr3z/n009/) post and a [Youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=R_z2MKvyals) of the numbers `0 0 1 1 2 1` ([rajb245 suggested](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/9652/what-is-encrypted-in-this-image/9653#comment35514_9653) the beeps heard could be Morse Code). So I try [/r/N001121](https://www.reddit.com/r/N001121) and [its only post](https://www.reddit.com/r/N001121/comments/2wjwcf/23015/). Dead end. Back to the original /r/N001109 post. There's a [single comment](https://www.reddit.com/r/N001109/comments/2wjr3z/n009/corgxo3):

```
150 164 164 160 163 072 057 057 167 167 167 056 162 145 144 144 151 164 056 143 157 155 057 162 057 116 060 061 061 060 070 057 015 012 015 012 123 110 101 114 114 040 127 105 077 040
```

Looks like octal. It decodes to (there's a space after the question mark):

```
https://www.reddit.com/r/N01108/

SHALL WE?
```

Following that takes us to [/r/N01108](https://www.reddit.com/r/N01108/) (obviously) with [its only post](https://www.reddit.com/r/N01108/comments/2wjtnm/alice/):

```
060 061 060 061 060 061 061 061 040 060 061 060 060 061 060 060 060 040 060 061 060 060 060 061 060 061 040 060 061 060 060 061 061 061 060 040 060 060 061 060 060 060 060 060 040 060 061 060 060 060 061 060 060 040 060 061 060 060 061 061 061 061 040 060 061 060 060 060 061 060 061 040 060 061 060 061 060 060 061 061 040 060 060 061 060 060 060 060 060 040 060 061 060 061 060 061 060 060 040 060 061 060 060 061 060 060 060 040 060 061 060 060 060 061 060 061 040 060 060 061 060 060 060 060 060 040 060 061 060 061 060 060 061 060 040 060 061 060 060 060 060 060 061 040 060 061 060 060 060 060 061 060 040 060 061 060 060 060 060 061 060 040 060 061 060 060 061 060 060 061 040 060 061 060 061 060 061 060 060 040 060 060 061 060 060 060 060 060 040 060 061 060 060 061 060 060 060 040 060 061 060 060 061 061 061 061 040 060 061 060 060 061 061 060 060 040 060 061 060 060 060 061 060 061 040 060 060 061 060 060 060 060 060 040 060 061 060 060 060 061 060 061 040 060 061 060 060 061 061 061 060 040 060 061 060 060 060 061 060 060 040 060 060 061 061 061 061 061 061 040 060 060 060 060 061 060 061 060 040 060 061 060 060 061 061 060 060 040 060 061 060 060 060 060 061 061 040 060 061 060 060 060 060 060 061 040 060 061 060 061 060 060 061 060 040 060 061 060 061 060 060 061 060 040 060 061 060 060 061 061 061 061 040 060 061 060 060 061 061 060 060 040 060 061 060 060 061 061 060 060 040 060 060 061 060 060 060 060 060 040 060 061 060 060 060 061 061 061 040 060 061 060 061 060 061 060 061 040 060 061 060 061 060 061 060 060 040 060 061 060 060 060 061 060 061 040 060 061 060 060 061 061 061 060 040 060 061 060 060 060 060 061 060 040 060 061 060 060 060 061 060 061 040 060 061 060 061 060 060 061 060 040 060 061 060 060 060 061 061 061 040 060 060 061 060 060 060 060 060 040 060 061 060 061 060 060 060 060 040 060 060 061 061 060 060 061 060 040 060 060 061 061 060 061 060 061 040 060 061 060 060 061 061 060 060 040 060 060 061 061 060 060 061 061 040 060 060 061 061 060 061 060 061 040 060 060 061 060 061 061 061 061 040 060 060 061 061 060 060 061 061 040 060 060 061 061 060 061 061 060 040 060 060 060 060 061 060 061 060 040 060 060 061 061 060 060 060 061 040 060 061 060 060 061 061 060 061 040 060 061 060 060 061 061 061 061 040 060 061 060 060 061 061 061 060 040 060 061 060 061 060 061 060 060 040 060 061 060 060 061 060 060 060 040
```

Another octal encoded string (with another random space at the end)!

```
01010111 01001000 01000101 01001110 00100000 01000100 01001111 01000101 01010011 00100000 01010100 01001000 01000101 00100000 01010010 01000001 01000010 01000010 01001001 01010100 00100000 01001000 01001111 01001100 01000101 00100000 01000101 01001110 01000100 00111111 00001010 01001100 01000011 01000001 01010010 01010010 01001111 01001100 01001100 00100000 01000111 01010101 01010100 01000101 01001110 01000010 01000101 01010010 01000111 00100000 01010000 00110010 00110101 01001100 00110011 00110101 00101111 00110011 00110110 00001010 00110001 01001101 01001111 01001110 01010100 01001000
```

Huh. Octal encoded binary encoded ASCII?

```
WHEN DOES THE RABBIT HOLE END?
LCARROLL GUTENBERG P25L35/36
1MONTH
```

A reference to the Gutenberg project and *Alice in Wonderland* (the post is titled "alice")? [The PDF](http://www.gutenberg.org/files/11/11-pdf.pdf)'s 25th page, lines 35 and 36 read:

```
'If everybody minded their own business,' the Duchess said in a hoarse growl, 'the world
would go round a deal faster than it does.'
```

That's a dead end for what I will assume to be a month. Back to the post, let's look at [the comment](https://www.reddit.com/r/N01108/comments/2wjtnm/alice/coroyfp):

```
newsyyyodhfssnviqwlbjnyqibxaeytcuy.kumetgn.bij
```

Maybe its reply?

```
31 32 34 20 31 31 31 20 31 32 34 20 31 31 34 20 31 30 35 20 31 31 37 20 31 30 36 20 31 31 32 20 31 32 30 20 31 30 37
```

Looks like hex. Decoding gets us:

```
124 111 124 114 105 117 106 112 120 107
```

An octal string. Decoding gets us:

```
TITLEOFJPG
```

Could the jumbled string of letters be a string encrypted with the title of the original image? Now we're stuck because we don't know the original name. I tried a reverse Google Image search, but that turned up nothing.

Comment: I at first didn't recognize it, but after playing it on my guitar, it sounds like that chord progression is Pachelbel's Canon. [Wikipedia's "Analysis" section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pachelbel%27s_Canon#Analysis) confirms this. Not sure how that fits in here yet.

Comment: TITLEOFJPG: check the exif data on the original image?

Comment: @JeffFerland I found a slightly different copy at [i.imgur.com/LMpMPUD.jpg](https://i.imgur.com/LMpMPUD.jpg), but both [that](http://regex.info/exif.cgi?dummy=on&imgurl=https%3A%2F%2Fi.imgur.com%2FLMpMPUD.jpg) and [the original](http://regex.info/exif.cgi?imgurl=https%3A%2F%2Fi.stack.imgur.com%2FSy2mt.jpg) turn up nothing. AFAICT, the one not hosted on Stack Imgur is only different in that it has a JFIF EXIF tag. Image data is identical.

Comment: This is brilliant !! Gabriel got his answer from what I believe to be a series of "grey dots" that can be found in the source image . Converting the image to a ppm then performing a hex dump gives a pattern that I didn't have time to study at work

Comment: @DamianNikodem The "grey dots" are a result of using `steghide` to encode the data.

Comment: Could it be that the first Link is in fact the original image and the OP designer of this riddle? Then the Filename would be "r6n5cBe.jpg"

Comment: @Falco that's what I thought, but to be safe, I'd use the one not hosed on Stack Imgur _also_. However, the problem now is to find out what encryption method is used. I doubt it's anything super complex.

Comment: Hi Cole, great post so far. I see a lot of "XY hints at Z" sentences. Would you care writing an answer to [this question](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/5905/what-characteristics-of-a-ciphertext-can-be-indicators-of-a-particular-cipher/5910#5910)?

Comment: are you benjamin gates?

Comment: @BmyGuest interesting question. However, the giveaways here were: new lines are `0d0a` and spaces are `20` in hex. Hex numbers are groups of two characters (`[0-9a-f]{2}`, octals are groups of three characters (`[0-3][0-7]{2}`). Nothing too hard when you're a programmer.

Comment: Has anyone decoded the youtube audio beeps? Sounds like Morse code to me.

Comment: @rajb245 Great suggestion, I never thought of that! I'll try that in a little bit.

Comment: @ColeJohnson - I decoded the Morse in February.  It provides this address K5ABX7SE for [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/K5ABX7SE). Then this hex string decodes to an octal string which decodes to  /r/n01108, where you have already been.

Answer (score 5):

Taking a similar path like Cole Johnson but with a different result.

Starting with the first comment: pastebin.com/szEs3Hhq by Gabriel Santos. This is the biggest doubt. I do not see a hint that the URL is embedded in that image.

Of course I find:

```
you've done well. Go deeper, and the rewards can be found. Difficulty will increase as you solve each test.
May you find your meaning.

486578206973206561737920656e6f7567682e204e65656420746f20676f206465657065723f0d0a0d0a4441426d696e46236d696e47444741

Let the hunt begin.
```

Decoding the hex gives:

```
irb(main):002:0> str = "486578206973206561737920656e6f7567682e204e65656420746f20676f206465657065723f0d0a0d0a4441426d696e46236d696e47444741"
=> "486578206973206561737920656e6f7567682e204e65656420746f20676f206465657065723f0d0a0d0a4441426d696e46236d696e47444741"
irb(main):005:0> str.to_byte_string  
=> "Hex is easy enough. Need to go deeper?\r\n\r\nDABminF#minGDGA"
```

Googling `DABminF#minGDGA` has a YouTube video as first hit https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=R_z2MKvyals
The narrator says `N0112`.
The video looks like this. Note the `434` in the upper left corner [image]

Finding this post https://www.reddit.com/r/N001121. Which now has a second comment.

```
66 61 40 66 66 40 66 60 40 64 60 40 66 61 40 66 64 40 66 61 40 64 60 40 66 61 40 66 66 40 66 63 40 64 60 40 66 61 40 66 66 40 66 64 40 64 60 40 66 61 40 66 64 40 66 65 40 64 60 40 66 61 40 66 64 40 66 62 40 64 60 40 66 61 40 66 65 40 66 61 40 64 60 40 66 61 40 66 65 40 66 66 40 64 60 40 66 64 40 66 60 40 64 60 40 66 61 40 66 65 40 66 63 40 64 60 40 66 66 40 66 62 40 64 60 40 66 66 40 66 65 40 64 60 40 66 61 40 66 63 40 66 61 40 64 60 40 66 61 40 66 65 40 66 61 40 64 60 40 66 61 40 66 61 40 66 60 40 64 60 40 66 61 40 66 64 40 66 66 40 64 60 40 66 61 40 66 62 40 66 62
```

Authenticity is questionable; could be created by a freeloader.
Nevertheless, I continue.

```
irb(main):007:0> str2 = '66 61 40 66 66 40 66 60 40 64 60 40 66 61 40 66 64 40 66 61 40 64 60 40 66 61 40 66 66 40 66 63 40 64 60 40 66 61 40 66 66 40 66 64 40 64 60 40 66 61 40 66 64 40 66 65 40 64 60 40 66 61 40 66 64 40 66 62 40 64 60 40 66 61 40 66 65 40 66 61 40 64 60 40 66 61 40 66 65 40 66 66 40 64 60 40 66 64 40 66 60 40 64 60 40 66 61 40 66 65 40 66 63 40 64 60 40 66 66 40 66 62 40 64 60 40 66 66 40 66 65 40 64 60 40 66 61 40 66 63 40 66 61 40 64 60 40 66 61 40 66 65 40 66 61 40 64 60 40 66 61 40 66 61 40 66 60 40 64 60 40 66 61 40 66 64 40 66 66 40 64 60 40 66 61 40 66 62 40 66 62'
#Some iterations of adding more and more transformations. 
#Converting from  octed and decimal in several iterations
#Finally this turns up:
irb(main):025:0> str2.split(" ").collect do |x| x.oct end.collect do |x| x.chr end.join("").split(" ").collect do |x| x.oct end.collect do |x| x.chr end.join("").split(" ").collect do |x| x.oct end.collect do |x| x.chr end.join ""
=> "pastebin k25YiHfR"
```

This pastebin URL shows this (http pastebin dot com/ k25YiHfR):

```
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
```

Decoding this twice:

```
irb(main):027:0> str3 = 'YjI1b.....'
irb(main):034:0> Base64.decode64(Base64.decode64(str3))
=> "<some explicit text about Mario and Yoshi; decode it yourselves>"
```

Conclusion: The entry point is questionable and if the riddle path was not already corrupted by some freeloader is also possible.

Comment: Damn, that Mario and Yoshi story is disgusting. Definitely corruption of the path or trolling on the part of someone (OP? guy who posted the pastebin?)

Comment: I can confirm that the pastebin is accurate: its encoded using steghide with no password.

Comment: How do you see the `434` in the upper left corner (it's just black to me)? Did you change your gamma or something?

Comment: @ColeJohnson It's very faint. Go right up to your screen and you've got a better chance of seeing it.

Comment: @Kslkgh It must have something to do with gamma for me because I can see it easily on my phone but not my computer

Answer (score 2):

Some additional "analysis" of the image (potentially useless). All based on the image downloaded here (as a BMP file)

- Image size 800 x 600 is not suspicious
- All RGB values are grey-values (No difference in red/green/blue)

  > *Considering grey-level values in further analysis only*.
- 4843 non-black (non-zero) pixels in total. The image below is a binary-map of those pixels.

[image: Non-zero-pixels-mask]

- A full pixel value histogram: http://pastebin.com/vZ7qHt7m
  [image: Histogram]
- Summing pixel grey-values horizontally & vertically in the both the original and the "binary mask" image yields:

  - [image: ImageSums]
  - vertical sum (original): http://pastebin.com/6cUTt7JQ
  - vertical sum (binary): http://pastebin.com/cprLUTHv
  - horizontal sum (original): http://pastebin.com/bQT2p5xj
  - horizontal sum (binary): http://pastebin.com/guq4xZpE

Comment: Those random white specs are what I believe contained the pastebin URL (steghide)