# There's an ARG I've been working on, and I'm stuck on this puzzle part II

Tags: mathematics, calculation-puzzle

Hees the first one incase you havent seen it.
[There's an ARG I've been working on, and I'm stuck on this puzzle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/10619/theres-an-arg-ive-been-working-on-and-im-stuck-on-this-puzzle)

So from that we got our password for this "problem" however we havent cracked this code yet, we've tried pufferfish and we're working on something else, if you think you have an answer please post it.
Heres the code

57]234($$†‡555$3;‡62510552]34)?125155:26))11†53-5$360‡†54$55833‡3]8$1-8$335†¶]‡¶28:[8$-?[4†51¶?†529¶]:¶28†¶)†2‡[]7$2?-[)51?[9;†1[?5:59[9?56¶?¢51.[4?

Comment: I am not sure that you understand the purpose of this site.  Good puzzles are welcome. Just throwing out some code is not a good puzzle.  Please read some good [guidelines here](http://meta.puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/1717/code-puzzles-what-not-to-do)

Comment: It is a puzzle, its just as the tags say, a calculation puzzle.

Comment: Would it be possible to include a few more details about the source and purpose of this ARG?

Answer (score 4):

This code is a modified version of the obscure [Gold-Bug](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Gold-Bug) cipher. Unfortunately the fact that the solution text is in a different language has meant that I can only give a partial answer.

The Gold Bug cipher is a substitution cipher. Employing the substitutions in the book gives the partially decoded text:

> a7wbghr\$\$doaaa\$gtoibaflaabwghsufbafaaybissffdagca\$gilodah\$aaeggogwe\$fce\$ggadvwovbey[e\$cu[hdafvudabmvwyvbedvsdbo[w7\$buc[safu[mtdf[uayam[muaivu¢afp[hu

Note that the \$, ¢, [ and 7 did not appear in the original story. The only letters that have not been used are J, K, Q, X, and Z, and I'd guess that four of those letters map to the 4 unknown symbols. Unfortunately the fact that it is in another language makes this difficult for me to do. Note that the ciphertext may have a transposition cipher applied on top of it, or it might have completely different substitutions for the symbols. It's hard to tell.

Comment: The Gold-Bug ... I **love** that story.

Comment: @Tryth - Wow. Nice job.