# A Favorite Film Cryptogram

Tags: cipher, knowledge

**Warning: This puzzle contains major spoilers regarding Star Wars: The Force Awakens. Do not proceed unless you are okay with that!**

I have a new friend, Valerie -- we just became acquainted recently while attending the same college class. She is fascinating, but a little eccentric.

I recently met my new friend, Valerie, for breakfast. Over the course of our conversation, she mentioned that she is an avid watcher of sci-fi and fantasy films. I'm a fan of the genre myself, so I asked her to name her favorite.

"Oh," she replied. "I'll have to think about that.  I'll tell you when I figure it out."

Honestly, I forgot all about the conversation until today.  I arrived to the class we share early, as I always do.  Valerie showed up just as the bell rang, just as she always does.  But today, as she passed me on her way to an empty seat, she dropped a folded piece of paper on my open textbook.

A bit perplexed, I unfolded the note and quickly skimmmed it, enough to see it was a numbered list referencing characters and events from Star Wars: The Force Awakens.  I immediately thought about the conversation we had had. "It's a strange way to present her answer," I thought, "but the meaning is clear enough."  I folded the paper back up and put it away in my backpack.

At the end of class, I caught Valerie's attention before she left.  "So the new Star Wars is your favorite film? It's quite good, but-".

"Don't be so sure," she said, cutting me off with a mysterious smile.  "There's more to my note than you have yet seen." With that, she left for her next class.

Frowning, I fished the note back out of my backpack and looked at it again, more closely this time.  Yes, something was strange, but **what did it mean?  What is the answer hidden in Valerie's note?**

> 1. The droid, BB-8, is R2-D2's child.
>  2. Kylo Ren's father is Han Solo.
>  3. And his mother is Leia! 
>  4. (Only in this movie, Leia's title is "Sergeant" instead of "Princess".)
>  5. Finn is a stormtrooper who defects.
>  6. Poe Dameron asks Finn to pilot a ship off of Jakku.
>  7. The ship Poe and Finn are in crashes on Jakku.
>  8. But fortunately we find out they both survived.
>  9. The girl, Rey, has a mysterious background.
>  10. It turns out that she can use the force.
>  11. She is also a very capable pilot.
>  12. She has a hard time leaving the aunt and uncle she lives with on Jakku.
>  13. But she does it because she has heard there's a powerful Jedi on Dagobah who can teach her.
>  14. Meanwhile, the evil regime has built a powerful weapon of mass destruction.
>  15. But this time, they've learned their lesson, and this one is NOT vulnerable in one small area where it can be attacked by small ships.
>  16. Kylo Ren murders Han Solo.
>  17. And Leia cries like a baby onscreen when Rey tells her what happened.
>  18. Rey finds Luke sitting in a cozy cottage drinking a cup of tea.
>  19. (Because of course it turns out there is a map pointing out exactly where Luke is.)
>  20. Which we only find in its entirety near the end of the plot because, apparently, droid mental health issues are a real thing -- poor R2-D2.

**Hint 1:**

> As noted in the comments, some items in the list are true and others are not. Once you figure out which are true and which are not, the trivia portion of this puzzle is done.

**Hint 2:**

> The order of the statements in the list is important.

**Hint 3:**

> Once you have the trivia part done, turn your attention to the other tag on this question. If you are inexperienced with these puzzle types, I refer you to [this excellent question](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/5905/what-characteristics-of-a-ciphertext-can-be-indicators-of-a-particular-cipher). Good luck!

Comment: Do you know the answer, was this just a story or did you just make if up?

Comment: Yes, I know the answer and yes, the story is made up.

Comment: Is it just me or did Rey not even have an aunt and uncle?

Comment: Good observation.

Comment: On further inspection: 2,3,5,7,8,9,10,14,16,19,20 are true the rest are false I believe.

Comment: You're starting off well, though I caution that I disagree with one of the items (one you think is false I intended to be true)

Comment: Maybe the one about Leia being sergeant? I though she was a general.

Comment: @Daedric 11, I think - she does seem to be a pretty good pilot

Comment: @LogicianWithAHat I couldn't remember her flying lol.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Building off of Daedric's answer:

If you interpret the true statements and false statements as

> B and A in a Bacon cipher,

you get the plaintext

> **TRON**, which is the answer.

Comment: Makes sense, I was wondering why the binary was divisible but 5.

Answer (score 5):

**Please note this is not the complete answer**
This is simply a formatted version of what I pointed out in the comments, and we have since learned it is a step towards completing this puzzle.

> **Each statement is either true or false.**
>  **False Statements**
>  1. The droid, BB-8, is R2-D2's child.
>  4. (Only in this movie, Leia's title is "Sergeant" instead of "Princess".)
>  6. Poe Dameron asks Finn to pilot a ship off of Jakku.
>  12. She has a hard time leaving the aunt and uncle she lives with on Jakku.
>  13. But she does it because she has heard there's a powerful Jedi on Dagobah who can teach her.
>  15. But this time, they've learned their lesson, and this one is NOT vulnerable in one small area where it can be attacked by small ships.
>  17. And Leia cries like a baby onscreen when Rey tells her what happened.
>  18. Rey finds Luke sitting in a cozy cottage drinking a cup of tea.
>  **True Statements**
>  2. Kylo Ren's father is Han Solo
>  3. And his mother is Leia!
>  5. Finn is a stormtrooper who defects.
>  7. The ship Poe and Finn are in crashes on Jakku.
>  8. But fortunately we find out they both survived.
>  9. The girl, Rey, has a mysterious background.
>  10. It turns out that she can use the force.
>  11. She is also a very capable pilot. *Thx to @LogicianWithAHat*
>  14. Meanwhile, the evil regime has built a powerful weapon of mass destruction.
>  16. Kylo Ren murders Han Solo.
>  19. (Because of course it turns out there is a map pointing out exactly where Luke is.)
>  20. Which we only find in its entirety near the end of the plot because, apparently, droid mental health issues are a real thing -- poor R2-D2.
>  **Binary**:
>  01101011111001010011

Comment: This is a good partial answer (I upvoted it). You are close!