# We interrupt your scheduled series for a pretzel rebus

Tags: visual, rebus

What does this rebus, drawn with pretzels, say? (This is what happens when I get bored with pretzels on the table... ;P)

<sub>Note: The 'scheduled series' mentioned is [this](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/40802/youll-need-thomas-jefferson-more-than-youll-expect-clue-twelve). <s>It still needs to be solved!</s> **Finally solved by @randal'thor!** :D</sub>

Overall picture:

[image: overall]

Individual pictures:

[image: first]

[image: second]

[image: third]

Note: That black dot in the second one is not important.

Comment: Are the different divider lengths of any importance?

Comment: @LukasRotter Nope.

Comment: Last question: Are you sure the deer on the right isn't actually suppossed to be a hind? :P (You don't have to answer it, I'm not sure if it's appropriate to ask for hints so early)

Comment: @LukasRotter It's a deer.

Comment: @LukasRotter With Zeus, you're on the right track. It's not Zeus, though, but it's related to that kinda thing.

Comment: This seems to be inspired by [The Curse of the Ancients](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/33864/the-curse-of-the-ancients)...

Comment: I wasn't actually seriously suggesting it was. The style just seemed similar in a way that amused me.

Comment: I want pretzels now :/

Comment: Do we need a pretzels-tag now? ;c) @Mithrandir Be careful, or your name is becoming 'cat' soon...

Comment: @BmyGuest o_o Why 'cat'?...

Comment: Sorry, you might not know. There was a time when a special set of riddles always ended up having the same (*cat*) solution and it became a sort of meme.

Comment: @BmyGuest Ah, okay. I'm sort of new still (50 days), so I didn't know. :P

Comment: @BmyGuest Ha! I'm glad someone else here still remembers the 'cat' riddles :-D

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The first panel shows

> a god and a small human, therefore the panel stands for **myth**.

The second panel shows

> a running human, therefore the panel stands for `run`. However the backwards pointing indicates that the word should be in past tense, so the panel ultimately stands for **ran**. (Thanks to @CWoods)

The third panel shows

> a **deer**

Now,

> say the three words out loud and you'll have the final solution: **Mithrandir**

Comment: Very nice, seems like the right answer. It seems that maybe there is an arrow in the second panel (since the guy seems to have two arms in front of him), so maybe the backwards arrow indicates the word should be in past tense?

Comment: Ah, ok. Wasn't sure about the proper pronounciation, as I'm not a native speaker. I'll add it to the answer.

Comment: Was confused what the answer meant until I looked at the poster's username.