# The second pretzel rebus

Tags: visual, rebus

<sub>This is the sequel to [this](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/41112/25966).</sub>

---

What does the below quote, written with pretzels, say?

Overall image:

[image: overallimage]

Mug shots:

<sub>Sorry, this first one is kinda blurry. But it's still recognizable.</sub>

[image: first]

[image: second]

[image: third]

<sub>(Next one's a bit blurry, sorry. But it doesn't really matter.)</sub>

[image: fourth]

[image: fifth]

---

[image: sixth]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'd say the solution is

> "In a hole in the ground there lived a hobbit"

Explanation:

Picture 1:

> The arrow is pointing **in** the square.

Picture 2:

> This is the picture of **a hole**

Picture 3:

> The arrow points to the **ground** next to a tree.

Picture 4:

> The arrow points **there**

Picture 5:

> A dude sitting down. **lived**?

Picture 6:

> *I have honestly no idea what this is!* EDIT: It's supposed to be Bilbo playing quoits

Comment: Obviously it's a bur- a hobbit! :P

Comment: Is this the right answer? If yes, I want to know your explanation of each drawing. I'm curious!

Comment: Yes, it is - I was just waiting for you to explain the last line. Hint: It's Bilbo. Doing something that he liked to do, before I knocked on his door.

Comment: He's... smoking? Is that a ring of smoke? But what's that thing on the right? And why is he fat? D:

Comment: He's fat because he's a hobbit... (It starts with a q. He's *throwing* the ring.)

Comment: After some googling I found the game "quoit". I haven't read the books yet (but I've wanting to do it for a long time) so I didn't know it :)

Comment: Last question: what's the explanation of pic 5?

Comment: It's someone sitting down. He lives there - so it's **lived**. I couldn't think of a better way to put it :/