# Quote in a rebus

Tags: rebus, quote

**What quote is hidden in the following rebus puzzle?** (Click on each image to enlarge.) The answer may be given in the form of an image if so desired.

---

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Amusing but much too easy :-).

Comment: @Gareth When studying [this previous rebus](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/42697/the-second-pretzel-rebus), I kept trying to make it fit [the answer to this one]. Given that it wasn't the correct answer then, I thought it was worth having a rebus for that quote anyway :-)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The answer:

> One does not simply walk into Mordor

Explanation:

> 1 = one
>  female deer/does = does
>  knot = not
>  sim card = sim
>  plywood = ply
>  walking man = walk
>  arrow = into
>  > = more/mor
>  door = dor

See also (credit to @MMAdams):

> [image]